# <a> html tag used for hyperlink doesn't work in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to make one word of a sentence as a hyperlink.
I have written it as :
Click on our <a href="http://www.google.co.in"> website </a> to know the details.
The markup property of the text field is also selected as "html".
But the hyperlink is not created.
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is pretty old, but if somebody need a code, I will add it here:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="220" y="45" width="406" height="60"/>
    <textElement markup="html">
        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Click on our"+"<u><font color='blue'><a href='http://www.google.co.in'>website</a></font></u>"]]> 
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML markups are only intended for the purpose of styling a text field.
You are looking for the "Hyperlink" option. It doesn't work for static text fields though, but when you right click on a text field you should find the item "Hyperlink" in the context menu. This allows you to link the field to an anchor, another report or a webpage.

Comment: By the way, for future readers of this question: The markup available in text fields was indeed quite limited. It was a boolean choice of whether to include markup, and it was for formatting. Now (JR 4.1+) you can choose the markup type (styled, rtf, html, none) and using "a" for a link works just like you would hope.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlinks are not supported by static text fields - they only work with text field.. it worked when i used a text field and as the expression entered static text in quotes "click here etc"
Then add a hyperlink by selecting hyperlink from the context menu..

Answer (score 0):

The htm markup seems to be extremely limited.  I have only found that it works for very basic html formating such as `<i>` and `<b>` tags.  I do not think anchors or lists or any 'fancier' markup with do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If HTML markup does not work, you can always configure the hyperlink property of a Jasper element. You'll find it in the **properties** window. Here is how to add an hyperlink to an image or a text field in Jaspersoft Studio 6.20.0:

[image]