# Why a link inside html markup is not working in RTF?

Tags: html, jasper-reports, textfield, rtf

I need a link inside **textField** in Jasper Reports.

I know there is *hyperlinkType="Reference"* in Jasper Reports and it works fine, but I need the link and text inside of ONE textField.

I use **html** **markup** with the following code:

```
<textField>
<reportElement positionType="Float" x="220" y="45" width="406" height="60"/>
<textElement markup="html">
    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
</textElement>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[
"Link: " +
"<u><font color='blue'><a href='http://adress'>Company Side</a></font></u>"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

It works fine in **PDF**. But it does not work as a link in **RTF**. "Company Side" is blue and undelined, but it is not a LINK.

What is needed to do to the link and text will be inside of one textField in RTF? Why the behavior in PDF and RTF is the difference?

I already have seen this questions:

- [<a> html tag used for hyperlink doesn't work in Jasper Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818439/a-html-tag-used-for-hyperlink-doesnt-work-in-jasper-report)
- [Create an external URL hyperlink with JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254009/create-an-external-url-hyperlink-with-jasperreports)

Comment: *JRRtfExporter* supports hyperlinks. You can try to play with [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.rtf.ignore.hyperlink*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.rtf.ignore.hyperlink) property. Are you using *hyperlinkReferenceExpression* & *hyperlinkType* at textField?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, I have tried. But in that case all text is a link. Only part of text should be a link, the rest should be a text for my task. This should be in one textField. Is it possible with _hyperlinkReferenceExpression & hyperlinkType_?

Comment: It is not a brilliant solution, but you can use several textFields for drawing text. One (or several) of this textField can has *hyperlinkReferenceExpression* attribute